# Wrong tensor type when trying to do the HuggingFace tutorial (pytorch)

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I've recently been trying to get hands on experience with the transformer library from Hugging Face. Since I'm an absolute noob when it comes to using Pytorch (and Deep Learning in general), I started with the introduction that can be found [here](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3?fw=pt).

Here is the code to install dependencies :

```
#!pip install transformers
!pip install transformers[sentencepiece] # includes transformers dependencies
!pip install datasets # datasets from huggingface hub
!pip install tqdm
```

Here's the code they propose to use to fine-tune BERT the MNPR dataset (used in the GLUE benchmark). This dataset includes two sentences per "sample", so in the tokenizer we have to use `sentence1` and `sentence2`.

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AdamW
from transformers import get_scheduler
import torch
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "mrpc")
checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"

# functions defining how the tokenizer works
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

def tokenize_function(example):
  return tokenizer(example["sentence1"], example["sentence2"], truncation=True)

# tokenizer will use dynamic padding (https://huggingface.co/course/chapter3/2?fw=pt)
tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

# remove unecessary columns from data and format in torch tensors
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(
  ["sentence1", "sentence2", "idx"]
)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.rename_column("label", "labels")
tokenized_datasets.set_format("torch")

train_dataloader = DataLoader(
  tokenized_datasets["train"], shuffle=True, batch_size=8, collate_fn=data_collator
)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(
  tokenized_datasets["validation"], batch_size=8, collate_fn=data_collator
)

# loading model and training requirements
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=5e-5)

num_epochs = 3
num_training_steps = num_epochs * len(train_dataloader)
lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
  "linear",
  optimizer=optimizer,
  num_warmup_steps=0,
  num_training_steps=num_training_steps
)
print(num_training_steps)

device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)

progress_bar = tqdm(range(num_training_steps))

# training loop:
model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for batch in train_dataloader:
    batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
    outputs = model(**batch)
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    progress_bar.update(1)
    # assert 1==0
```

This works perfectly fine for me in Google Colab. I wanted to do the same thing with another dataset `sst2`. The code I use is very similar to the one above. The only few lines of code that change are the lines to import the data and the tokenizer (we have one sentence per feature instead of two). I have double-checked and the tokenizer works fine. Here is my code :

```
# imports
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset # datasets from huggingface
# tokenization
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, DataCollatorWithPadding
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
# training
from transformers import AdamW, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, get_scheduler
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

# Hyperparameters
batch_size = 8
learning_rate = 5e-5
num_epochs = 3
num_warmup_steps = 0

# load dataset and choosing checkpoint
raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "sst2")
checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
# load tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

# tokenization of dataset
def tokenize_function(example):
  return tokenizer(example["sentence"], truncation=True)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)
tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(["sentence", "idx"])
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.rename_column("label", "labels") 
tokenized_datasets.set_format("torch")

# setting DataLoader
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
  tokenized_datasets["train"], shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size, collate_fn=data_collator
)
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(
  tokenized_datasets["validation"], batch_size=batch_size, collate_fn=data_collator
)

# import model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=1)

# setup training loop
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

num_training_steps = num_epochs * len(train_dataloader)
print(num_training_steps)
lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
    "linear",
    optimizer=optimizer,
    num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
    num_training_steps=num_training_steps
)
# chose device (GPU or CPU)
device = torch.device("cuda") if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)

progress_bar = tqdm(range(num_training_steps))

model.train()
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
  for batch in train_dataloader:
    batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()} 
    for k,v in batch.items():
      print(f"key={k},v.dtype={v.dtype}, type(v)={type(v)}")
    outputs = model(**batch)
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss.backward()
        
    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    progress_bar.update(1)
```

And here's the error I get :

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7893d7715ac2> in <module>()
     69     outputs = model(**batch)
     70     loss = outputs.loss
---> 71     loss.backward()
     72 
     73     optimizer.step()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables, inputs)
    147     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    148         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
--> 149         allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    150 
    151 

RuntimeError: Found dtype Long but expected Float
```

This seems like a very silly mistake, but like I said I'm an absolute pytorch noob and it's difficult for me to know where to start solving this issue. I have checked the type of the values in `batch.items()` and in both cases, they are all `torch.int64` (or `torch.long`). I tried to change the `attention_mask` and `input_ids` values to `torch.float32`, but I got the same error message.

Thanks in advance.

Python version and packages :

- python 3.7.20
- Pytorch 1.9.0+cu102
- transformers 4.8.2
- GPU : Tesla T4 (also tried with tesla P4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. The problem comes from the line

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=1)
```

Since the dataset has 2 classes, the correct way of calling the model should be

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)
```

With this modification, my code now works.